# Avoid Duplicate Names of Account using Validation Rule

Tags: validation

**How to Avoid Duplicate Names of Account while Creating or Editing the Account Record using Validation Rules**

Comment: Plesae anyone Share the Formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Duplicate Rule functionality provided by Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US

This will help you to avoid duplicate records in salesforce.

Comment: Nice.One suggestion though, do not provide link only answers.You can provide details like how to setup duplicate rules etc.That way it would be more beneficial for community.

Comment: How to set Matching Rule for avoiding Duplicate Names in Account Record